# beginner to use assimp in ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to use Assimp in my upcoming ios project but having hard time to make it work. I followed the instructions from this:

[How to build ASSIMP Library for iOS (Device and Simulator) with boost-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691927/how-to-build-assimp-library-for-ios-device-and-simulator-with-boost-library)

But Terminal keep telling me this:

```
rm: CMakeCache.txt: No such file or directory
/Users/hengchinsoon/Desktop/assimp/port/iOS/build_ios.sh: line 40: cmake: command not found
Building armv6 library
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `assimp'.  Stop.
cp: ./lib/libassimp.a: No such file or directory
rm: CMakeCache.txt: No such file or directory
/Users/hengchinsoon/Desktop/assimp/port/iOS/build_ios.sh: line 51: cmake: command not found
Building armv7 library
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `assimp'.  Stop.
cp: ./lib/libassimp.a: No such file or directory
rm: CMakeCache.txt: No such file or directory
/Users/hengchinsoon/Desktop/assimp/port/iOS/build_ios.sh: line 62: cmake: command not found
Building i386 library
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `assimp'.  Stop.
cp: ./lib/libassimp.a: No such file or directory
rm: ./lib/libassimp.a: No such file or directory
```

So I checked the assimp root folder and found out that there isn't any lib folder(which from the github descriptions, that is for windows usage). So i just made lib folder and try again. But still not working.

1. Can anybody share with me which part I did wrongly? Thanks!
2. Say if I successfully install whatever I need to install, then how to really use the library?
   Should I copy the lib/ios/ folder into my ios projects?

What I want to do is to import some .blend files then I can experiment on the shader and other cool stuffs.

I am decent ios developer and have basic understanding of OpenGL ES. Somehow the Assimp document confused me about what it does. I am not so sure if I don't understand Assimp at the core concept level or at the programming level. But I am still convinced that it is very flexible and powerful.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you are using the "buil_ios.sh" script, in that script there are a few errors.

You should first download Cmake from : [Cmake Download](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html)

Install Cmake and then do the following.

First of all, I think that besides that output you are getting some message that tells you that some options that you put in the Cmake are not being used. That's because in the script the name of some vars are not well written.

Besides this, you should change the CMakeLists.txt file so you don't get an error while you try to build the library:

## Define here the needed parameters

set (ASSIMP_SV_REVISION 1023) <-- It should be less than 1024.

set (ASSIMP_VERSION ${ASSIMP_VERSION_MAJOR}) <-- here you will find some parameters like this. (parameter0).(parameter1)... 
Mac OS doesn't like to put names using this nomenclature: parameter0.parameter1.paramter.2.a I guess it's because of the '.'.

So after a long day I finally managed to build the library. Another options is to get the library compiled from the project openframeworks, the path it's this: "/addons/ofxAssimpModelLoader/libs/assimp/lib/ios/assimp.a"

[Here you have a link to the library](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/addons/ofxAssimpModelLoader/libs/assimp/lib/ios)

There you can find the library already compiled for the arm6 arm7 and i386 architectures.

I'm going to put you the script modified here.

```
#!/bin/sh
# build.sh

#######################
# BUILD ASSIMP for iOS and iOS Simulator
#######################

BUILD_DIR="./lib/ios"

IOS_BASE_SDK="5.0"
IOS_DEPLOY_TGT="3.2"

setenv_all()
{
    # Add internal libs
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2"
    export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2"
    export CXXCPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2"
    export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
    export LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld
    export AR=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ar
    export AS=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/as
    export NM=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/nm
    export RANLIB=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ranlib
    export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/"

    export CPPFLAGS=$CFLAGS
    export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
}

setenv_arm6()
{
    unset DEVROOT SDKROOT CFLAGS CC LD CPP CXX AR AS NM CXXCPP RANLIB LDFLAGS CPPFLAGS CXXFLAGS
    export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
    export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS$IOS_BASE_SDK.sdk
    export CFLAGS="-arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -miphoneos-version-min=$IOS_DEPLOY_TGT -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/"
    setenv_all
    rm CMakeCache.txt
    cmake  -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./port/iOS/IPHONEOS_ARM6_TOOLCHAIN.cmake -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON -DASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON
}

setenv_arm7()
{
    unset DEVROOT SDKROOT CFLAGS CC LD CPP CXX AR AS NM CXXCPP RANLIB LDFLAGS CPPFLAGS CXXFLAGS
    export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
    export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS$IOS_BASE_SDK.sdk
    export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -miphoneos-version-min=$IOS_DEPLOY_TGT -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/"
    setenv_all
    rm CMakeCache.txt
    cmake  -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./port/iOS/IPHONEOS_ARM7_TOOLCHAIN.cmake -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON -DASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON
}

setenv_i386()
{
    unset DEVROOT SDKROOT CFLAGS CC LD CPP CXX AR AS NM CXXCPP RANLIB LDFLAGS CPPFLAGS CXXFLAGS
    export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
    export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator$IOS_BASE_SDK.sdk
    export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT -miphoneos-version-min=$IOS_DEPLOY_TGT"
    setenv_all
    rm CMakeCache.txt
    cmake  -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./port/iOS/IPHONEOS_i386_TOOLCHAIN.cmake -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON -DASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB=ON
}

create_outdir()
{
    for lib_i386 in `find $BUILD_DIR/i386 -name "lib*\.a"`; do
        lib_arm6=`echo $lib_i386 | sed "s/i386/arm6/g"`
        lib_arm7=`echo $lib_i386 | sed "s/i386/arm7/g"`
        lib=`echo $lib_i386 | sed "s/i386\///g"`
        echo 'Creating fat binary...'
        lipo -arch armv6 $lib_arm6 -arch armv7 $lib_arm7 -arch i386 $lib_i386 -create -output $lib
    done
    echo 'Done! You will find the libaries and fat binary library in /lib/ios'
}
cd ../../

rm -rf $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR/arm6 $BUILD_DIR/arm7 $BUILD_DIR/i386

setenv_arm6
echo 'Building armv6 library'
make clean
make assimp -j 8 -l
cp ./lib/libassimp.a $BUILD_DIR/arm6/

setenv_arm7
echo 'Building armv7 library'
make clean
make assimp -j 8 -l
cp ./lib/libassimp.a $BUILD_DIR/arm7/


setenv_i386
echo 'Building i386 library'
make clean
make assimp -j 8 -l
cp ./lib/libassimp.a $BUILD_DIR/i386/

rm ./lib/libassimp.a

create_outdir
```

Comment: Hi xinoman12, I followed step by step of your instruction but after set (ASSIMP_VERSION ${ASSIMP_VERSION_MAJOR}) I am not sure what to do. I tried open cmake and look for a file to run but all file are gray-outed. what do cmake do actually? Thanks!

Comment: I figure out how to use cmake but there is some error: 'Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find Boost
Unable to find the Boost header files. Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing Boost's headers.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:83 (MESSAGE):
  Boost libraries (http://www.boost.org/) not found.  You can build a
  non-boost version of Assimp with slightly reduced functionality by
  specifying -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON.
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!' Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: OK, I found out the problem. There is a boost file missing. So I have to set it to ENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND = ON to not have problem on generating file.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that an alternative to this is to use openframeworks since it already incorporate assimp lib.

http://www.openframeworks.cc/download/

look for ios version. and inside there is a folder contain example/ios/assimpExample/ folder would be a good starting point.

Have fun!:D

Answer (score 0):

The boost root for me on Mac with the latest version of Homebrew is the following:

```
BOOST_ROOT=~/.homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.53.0
```

Your version of boost may be different, so the last folder will vary. But as of a recent homebrew version, Cellar gets install within the current user's home directory.