# Is it possible to use AssImp in a WP8 Direct3D application?

Tags: 3d, windows-phone-8, arm, windows-phone, direct3d

I'm making an application that would greatly benefit from being able to import a bunch of various model file types, hence my interest in assimp.

However, it appears that compiling the project for ARM is more difficult than it seems and since I am not an expert at compiling foreign systems I'm not having much luck using it in my WP8 app.

Has anyone been able to successfully use AssImp in a WP8 app? I see that [others have been able to make it work for an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691927/how-to-build-assimp-library-for-ios-device-and-simulator-with-boost-library), so compiling it for WP8 must not be impossible, but it may be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long story short, it is possible and after a couple days of fiddling, I managed to port it over.

The way I did it probably wasn't the best way to do it, but I'll explain it here anyways:

1. I spent a lot of time trying to compile the library separately then linking it.

   a. I was able to successfully build it for both ARM and x86/x64 but using this method I was unable to link it.

   b. I also managed to built it by adding source files and dependencies to a blank WP8 static library template.

   c. The times when I did get to link properly, I would get a runtime error saying that a module could not be found.
2. Through the effort I spent trying to get the above approach to work, I became really good at configuring a VS2012 project to properly compile AssImp, so I went for a more direct approach to avoid having to link and just added the AssImp source and its dependencies to my main WP8 project.

   a. There are a number of strange things you have to do to get AssImp properly configured.

   b. The most important one is making sure you have all of the dependencies (namely boost) and the additional files AssImp needs that are not in its source code directory. This includes a few version headers and a contrib directory.

   c. After you are sure that the includes are properly set up and that all of the necessary code is known to the compiler, you will have to do some file hacking to get around compiler issues.

   d. Most of the slight changes you have to make to port it are easy, but some are uglier, like one where you have to comment out some #includes in windows.h so that you aren't trying to bring in unused and incompatible headers.
3. After that, you should be able to get the entire project compiling and deploying! I have managed to load in and render models on both the WP8 emulator and the device itself.

If anyone needs help or if I can send you a version of my project that doesn't have my application code let me know!